# Glass fish server not starting

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

Hi am creating a web application using NetBeans 6.9.1 IDE and am trying to deploy GlassFuish server without success.

Comment: Deployment and startup are not the same thing. Please copy and paste the error message so we can see what's really the problem. From your description, it could be basically anything.

Comment: stack trace error message needed

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_ball - I tried this, but it didn't give me any information.

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds silly, but are you sure Glassfish won't start? It is under Start/Programs/Sun/Start Default Server.

If that is what you are doing, I want you to know that I have had a problem with GlassFish not starting. You may want to check your log to see what kind of error you are getting Sun/AppServer/domains/domain1/log/server

Review that and see what that says. It may be giving you a bunch of different errors. In general, though - if she won't start she needs to be uninstalled.

So, uninstall both applications.

Before you install anything make sure that you have the correct jdk installed. For instance, if you are installing NetBeans 6.9.1 IDE, go back and check to make sure you are installing the correct JDK first. I am sorry I don't know what JDK goes with this, but if you check the page/documentation for NetBeans 6.9.1, it should tell you.

Hello, try a custom deployment after, when you do the custom install, since this is a bundle, uncheck the following:

Prelude (Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v3 prelude) -- if you see that, if not, just keep going.

Also, do you have any system or environment variables that need to be set? What os are you working on?